# How the python2 deal the string and unicode in internal?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I'm confused with python's unicode/str processes. I have faced some situations in python2.

The following sentence wrote in a py file with utf8 encoding in IDE pycharm.

1. `print "hello! %s" % u"中国"`
2. `print "hello! %s" % "中国"`
3. `print u"hello! %s" % "中国"`

Only situation 3 raise decode error：

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128).

Can somebody tell me how the python deal this sentence. and why has the results?

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the print statements, you can see a bit more detail:

```
>>> "hello! %s" % u"中国"
u'hello! \u4e2d\u56fd'
>>> "hello! %s" % "中国"
'hello! \xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd'
>>> u"hello! %s" % "中国"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This gives us a clue what's going on. Whenever any unicode string is involved, Python tries to convert the other side to unicode; and, as usual, without any instructions to the contrary it will always assume the encoding is ASCII.

In the first case, it tries to convert the "hello" bytestring to unicode; since there are no non-ASCII characters, this works fine, and the result can safely be interpolated with the existing unicode string.

In the second case, both sides are bytestrings, so no conversion is attempted; the result is still a bytestring.

In the third case, "hello" is already unicode so it tries to convert the other side; but since those are non-ASCII characters, it fails. Specifying the encoding directly does work, however:

```
>>> u"hello! %s" % "中国".decode('utf-8')
u'hello! \u4e2d\u56fd'
```

Comment: ok, thanks.  I got two information from your answer.  1. python will not convert bytestrings to unicode when whey are all bytestrings.  And is there some documentation??     2. the third situation. the file is marked with utf8 encoding. How and why python think it is ASCIl encoding.